# Notify when normal user changes to root?

Tags: linux, ssh, cpanel, whm

Would it be possible that when a normal user logs in to root via `su` command an email notification will be sent?

Comment: Why are your normal users allowed to even execute `su`? At least on my system every user that wants to use `su` needs to be in `wheel`.

Comment: The approach is bad, any user who becomes root via `su` can also remove such an email notification. Your users should only be allowed to execute a very small set of commands as root, and only using `sudo`. Use the `/etc/sudoers` file to configure it accordingly (see the sudoers manpage).

Comment: @speakr Well my plan is only one normal user will be given root, I want to do this just to prevent brute forcing root. So direct root is disabled and that single normal user must use `su`

Comment: Define "brute forcing root".  Then explain how this will prevent it.

Comment: @fran SSH brute force attack. I already have my SSH on different port as well as blocking failed login attempts but a little more security like this won't hurt. How this works is, in case the brute-forcer finds out the port, he will still have to know the username because root is disabled.

Comment: @IMB So did you mean to write `ssh` instead of `su` in your question?  I don't see how your explanation has anything to do with `su`.

Comment: @Fran No. Well when the username logs in to SSH he then use `su` instead direct root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution would be creating a script which sends an email and executes a shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "sudo was used" | mail -s "sudo notification" your@mailaddress
exec bash
```

**Be sure to protect this script against any access from unprivileged users (see the lower part of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/440403/138199))!**

Then force privileged user *joe* to execute the script via restrictive `sudo` permissions.

An example for `/etc/sudoers`:

```
joe    ALL = (root) /absolute/path/to/your/script.sh
```

Now *joe* can call `sudo /absolute/path/to/your/script.sh` and gets a root shell while you are notified.

**However, be aware that once *joe* gets the root shell he owns your system, i.e. nothing keeps him from modifying your script, the sudoers file, and so on.**