# proper way of using setuid permission in linux

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, file-permissions, setuid

I created two file , one `abc.sh` and another `myfile` . The content of `abc.sh` is :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hi" >> myfile
```

The current permission and owner for both file is:
`abc.sh  : rwsrw-r-x  owner -> main(user) main(group)`

`myfile  : -rw-rw-r--  owner -> main(user) main(group)`

Note : the setuid bit is set on `abc.sh` file.

Now , if login as user `user2` and run `abc.sh` file as `user2` who is not owner and does not belong to group . I expect the script to be run successfully and content to be updated in `myfile` ,since the setuid is set and script will run as user `main`. also `myfile` has write permission for `main` user .

However ,  I still get permission denied error ?
What is the reason for it ? please , correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: Read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2910/108618) and maybe [this](https://superuser.com/q/440363/432690).

Comment: As said in the answers linked by @KamilMaciorowski, Linux ignores setuid bit on scripts. If you really need to run the script setuid, you must use a binary wrapper like the one presented in the second link.

Comment: Please don't mind me closing your question as a duplicate of a newer question (and not the other way around). [There is no penalty upon your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841/355310). Treat it as maintenance.